# Getting Error while publishing to Facebook from my App

Tags: java

I am getting the below error when we are trying to publish the data on Facebook from our App(via Java). We have submitted our App for review as per the policy change from Facebook. but currently we are trying resolve the below error, till the time our app is in review process.

> *Facebook Posting: Got Error:Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: (#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not
>   available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for
>   your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use
>   our Sharing products instead.*

we are using the restfb-1.6.12 version

```
FacebookClient fbClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(token);
 FacebookType response=null;
 response = fbClient.publish(page,
                    FacebookType.class,
                    BinaryAttachment.with(_map.substring(_map.lastIndexOf(File.separator)),
                    new FileInputStream(_map)),
                    Parameter.with("message", this._comment));
```

but we are getting the above mentioned error. Could anyone please let us know is there any alternate class present in restfb that we can use to overcome this issue. 
Is there any alternate API that is used in restfb which can allow us to publish data on Facebook page.

Facebook suggested : Developers currently utilizing publish_actions are encouraged to switch to Facebook's Share dialogs for web, iOS and Android.(https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/24/new-facebook-platform-product-changes-policy-updates/)
so is there any class in restfb using which we can use Facebook's Share dialogs?

Thanks

Comment: Facebook has removed this permission from most apps, except for a few approved exceptions. You won't be able to publish until you clear the review process, and trying to work around it is probably going to get approval denied. If the app is user facing, then you should swap to a ShareDialog.

Answer (score 0):

since you are trying to post content on facebook using your app you will have to provide publish_actions permissions.It is pretty clear from the message.

Comment: Okay..so I think for publish_actions permissions we need to submit the app to Facebook for review. if this is the case then we have submitted the app for review. But currently we are looking for any alternate API if any present in restfb, so that we can publish the content on facebook till the time our app is in Review process since it may take longer time to get the app reviewed..Please let me know if anyone has any idea about this..Thanks